Java Foreign Function & Memory API, problems with Locale
Long short story, I've been calling the native Lammps using the latest Foreign Function & Memory API (Project Panama) in JDK 22.
I have problems with the locale.
atof will parse 2.2598258677677969 as 2 because on my system localeconv()->decimal_point is indeed ,.
I've been trying to set on terminal export LC_ALL=C and adding in the native code itself.
#include <clocale>
setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");

But I didn't have any success so far. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the native environment.
My OS is Linux (Ubuntu).
To reproduce:
val l = Linker.nativeLinker()
val d = FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.JAVA_DOUBLE, ValueLayout.ADDRESS)
val atof = l.downcallHandle(l.defaultLookup().find("atof").get(), d)
val res = atof.invoke(Arena.global().allocateFrom("2.2598258677677969")) as Double
println(res)

On native, this:
    auto a = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
    utils::logmesg(this, "old locale {}\n", a);

prints the following

old locale LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_NAME=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=it_IT.UTF-8

locale -a

C
C.utf8
POSIX
de_AT.utf8
de_BE.utf8
de_CH.utf8
de_DE.utf8
de_IT.utf8
de_LI.utf8
de_LU.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
it_CH.utf8
it_IT.utf8


in Java you would do Locale.setDefault(Locale.ROOT);

nope, no change..

A [MCVE] might improve your Question.

What does setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL) return? Have you tried calling setlocale from Java?

atof() in C code? Why would be a Java problem? As @BasilBourque mentioned a [mre] is needed.

@BasilBourque minimal reproducible example added, it's a full prototype, so it's not easy.

@aled yes, on native. It's a Java problem because the Python original Mala works fine, when it calls the native Lammps, this parse the float properly

I suggest trying to reproduce just by calling atof directly, that won't require people to clone and build a bunch of repos. e.g. Linker l = Linker.nativeLinker(); var atof = l.downcallHandle(l.defaultLookup().find("atof").get(), FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.JAVA_DOUBLE, ValueLayout.ADDRESS)); double res = (double) atof.invoke(Arena.global().allocateFrom("2.2598258677677969"));

@JornVernee thanks a lot Jorn, that's actually very smart and much more efficient, sorry, but I'm quite burn from this..

I'm able to reproduce, but setting export LC_ALL=C works for me. What happens if you print out the variable with System.getenv("LC_ALL") just before invoking atof? (I'm assuming you have the locale installed. i.e. it's listed in locale -a)

for locale -a I updated the question. Sorry, but it's not clear to me how shall I apply that export if I run the whole via Idea, I think this might have to do with Idea or Gradle.. am I right?

For Kotlin and Intellij IDEA, there should be an Environment variables:  field in the Kotlin run configuration where you can set it.

done, solved here as well.. uff, thanks a lot, if you want to post it as a proper answer I'll be more than glad to accept it

I can reproduce your issue if I set my LC_NUMERIC locale to it_IT.utf8:
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC(), Arena.global().allocateFrom("it_IT.utf8"));
var res = atof(Arena.global().allocateFrom("2.2598258677677969"));
System.out.println(res); // 2.0

As you've found, setting the LC_ALL environment variable to C should fix the issue, and make atof return 2.259825867767797. You can make sure that LC_ALL is set correctly by printing out the result of System.getenv("LC_ALL") just before the call to atof.

As an alternative, you could explicitly set LC_ALL (or just LC_NUMERIC) to C at the start of your program, with a call to setlocale:
setlocale(LC_ALL(), Arena.global().allocateFrom("C"));


Note that LC_ALL and LC_NUMERIC are implementation-defined, so for the above snippets,  I'm using a jextract-ed interface for the C standard library, which will give me the right values of LC_ALL and LC_NUMERIC. See the sample here.
To generate the interface, install jextract and Java 22, add the bin directory of both to your PATH, and then run the following 2 commands:
$ jextract --output src -t libc --header-class-name LibC 'libc.h'
$ javac -d classes src/**/*.java

The libc.h file just contains #includes of all the C standard library header files, minus stdbit.h and stdckdint.h which are too new at the time of writing.
That should generate an src directory with the extracted sources, and spit out all the compiled classes in a classes directory, which you can then add to the class path of your JVM application. The generated classes and functions can be imported with:
import static libc.LibC.*;
import libc.*;

